# How to skip the creating the root node on a treeview?

Tags: c#

How would you modify this code to skip creating the root node and create only the other nodes?

```
    void ListDirectory(TreeView treeView, string path)
    {
        treeView.Nodes.Clear();
        var rootDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        treeView.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(rootDirectoryInfo));
    }


    TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
    {
        var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name);

        foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
        {
            directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));
        }

        return directoryNode;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
void ListDirectory(TreeView treeView, string path)
{
    treeView.Nodes.Clear();
    var rootDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);

    foreach (var directory in rootDirectoryInfo.GetDirectories())
    {
        treeView.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));
    }
}

TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
{
    var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name);

    foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
    {
        directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));
    }

    return directoryNode;
}
```